# Как объединить несколько столбцов добавлением снизу со смещением по дате?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть такой фрейм данных: df.head(10)

```
    Time        Open   High   Low    Close  Volume
0   2007-01-01  1.3190 1.3217 1.3165 1.3212 1995282
1   2007-01-02  1.3213 1.3295 1.3210 1.3272 2009661
2   2007-01-03  1.3270 1.3290 1.3146 1.3169 2016603
3   2007-01-04  1.3168 1.3178 1.3070 1.3086 2007990
4   2007-01-05  1.3086 1.3102 1.2980 1.2999 1916561
5   2007-01-07  1.3009 1.3014 1.3000 1.3003 96987
6   2007-01-08  1.3005 1.3038 1.2972 1.3035 2008364
7   2007-01-09  1.3035 1.3051 1.2985 1.2991 2000772
8   2007-01-10  1.2992 1.3000 1.2926 1.2934 2024197
9   2007-01-11  1.2934 1.3012 1.2880 1.2891 2006027
```

Как можно преобразовать таблицу в следующий вид:

```
         1      2      3      4
0 Close 1.3212 1.3272 1.3169 1.3086
  High  1.3217 1.3295 1.3290 1.3178
  Low   1.3165 1.3210 1.3146 1.3070
  Open  1.3190 1.3213 1.3270 1.3168
1 Close 1.3272 1.3169 1.3086 1.2999
  High  1.3295 1.3290 1.3178 1.3102
  Low   1.3210 1.3146 1.3070 1.2980
  Open  1.3213 1.3270 1.3168 1.3086
```

То есть по id идет смещение: первый блок начинается с 2007-01-01, второй - с 2007-01-02, третий - с 2007-01-03 и так далее

Comment: Что-то исходная и конечная таблица ну никак по значениям не соотносятся... а должны - на то и пример.

Comment: можете уточнить вопрос? Что вы называете блоком? Что вы понимаете под "id"?   Стоит подробнее описать как вы получили желаемую таблицу. PS Откуда берутся значения для Open - их нет в исходной таблице

Comment: Извините, действительно ошибся при вводе данных. Сейчас всё поправил. Блок - это 4 строки под номером id